# Nested groupings with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

In the `data.table` below, I have information on the  composition of teams participating to projects. The variable `id` tells the team id while the variable `event` gives the project number. The variable `freqrel` describes the composition of the teams (you can see that freqrel adds up to 1 within every team).

```
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L), event = c("127b", "127b", "127b", "127b", 
"127b", "127b", "127b", "127b", "127b", "125t", "125t", "125t", 
"125t", "125t", "125t"), membr = c("engineer", "mathematician", 
"physicist", "mathematician", "physicist", "surgeon", "dentist", 
"mathematician", "programmer", "physicist", "sociologist", "surgeon", 
"musician", "sociologist", "surgeon"), freqrel = c(0.4, 0.4, 
0.2, 0.166666666666667, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
0.5, 0.166666666666667, 0.75, 0.125, 0.125, 0.444444444444444, 
0.444444444444444, 0.111111111111111)), .Names = c("id", "event", 
"membr", "freqrel"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), sorted = c("id", "event"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x039a24a0>)
```

The way I see the data are split into nested groups. The first division occurs at the project level (straight line) and the second at the team level (dashed line).

```
    id event         membr   freqrel
 1:  1  127b      engineer 0.4000000
 2:  1  127b mathematician 0.4000000
 3:  1  127b     physicist 0.2000000
--------------------------------------
 4:  2  127b mathematician 0.1666667
 5:  2  127b     physicist 0.5000000
 6:  2  127b       surgeon 0.3333333
--------------------------------------
 7:  3  127b       dentist 0.3333333
 8:  3  127b mathematician 0.5000000
 9:  3  127b    programmer 0.1666667
_____________________________________
10:  4  125t     physicist 0.7500000
11:  4  125t   sociologist 0.1250000
12:  4  125t       surgeon 0.1250000
--------------------------------------
13:  5  125t      musician 0.4444444
14:  5  125t   sociologist 0.4444444
15:  5  125t       surgeon 0.1111111
```

From this starting condition I would like to make teams within the same project perfectly comparable by adding to each of them also the `membr` types that the team doesn't feature, assigning them freqrel=0. The result should be this:

```
    id event         membr   freqrel
 1:  1  127b       dentist 0.0000000  
 2:  1  127b      engineer 0.4000000
 3:  1  127b mathematician 0.4000000
 4:  1  127b     physicist 0.2000000
 5:  1  127b    programmer 0.0000000
 6:  1  127b       surgeon 0.0000000
--------------------------------------
 7:  2  127b       dentist 0.0000000  
 8:  2  127b      engineer 0.0000000
 9:  2  127b mathematician 0.1666667
 10: 2  127b     physicist 0.5000000
 11: 2  127b    programmer 0.0000000
 12: 2  127b       surgeon 0.3333333    
--------------------------------------
 13: 3  127b       dentist 0.3333333 
 14: 3  127b      engineer 0.0000000
 15: 3  127b mathematician 0.5000000
 16: 3  127b     physicist 0.0000000
 17: 3  127b    programmer 0.1666667
 18: 3  127b       surgeon 0.0000000   
_____________________________________
 19: 4  125t      musician 0.0000000
 20: 4  125t     physicist 0.7500000
 21: 4  125t   sociologist 0.1250000
 22: 4  125t       surgeon 0.1250000
--------------------------------------
 23: 5  125t      musician 0.4444444
 24: 5  125t     physicist 0.0000000
 25: 5  125t   sociologist 0.4444444
 26: 5  125t       surgeon 0.1111111
```

In other words, after dividing the data with `by` using `event` as a key, I need to divide a second time and compare the chunks of data obtained with the second splitting.
But here the problem is that I don't know how to reference the first chunk obtained with `by` and then how to split again and do the comparisons among the pieces of the database. Do you have an idea how I could sort this out?

I'd be extremely thankful if you could help me. Really.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an easy way:

```
setkey(dt, id, membr)
ans <- dt[, .SD[CJ(unique(id), unique(membr))], by=list(event)]
```

Then, you can just replace the `NA` with 0's as follows:

```
ans[is.na(freqrel), freqrel := 0.0]
```

---

Some explanation: Your problem boils down to this - for every `event`, you want all possible combinations of `id, membr` so that you can then perform a join on this all-combination *within that grouping* using `.SD`.

So, first we group by `event`, and within that, we first get all combinations of `id, membr` with the help of `CJ` (which will have a key set to all columns by default). However, to perform a join we need to have the key set for `.SD`. Therefore, we set the `key` for `dt` to `id, membr` upfront. Thus, we perform a join within each group and that gives you the intended result. Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: I am so thankful. I will study your solution to understand it completely. Thank you so much.

Comment: It helped a lot. It was a great solution and I am glad I asked the question because your answer made me realize that I would never have made it alone. Many thanks. A great lesson of coding style.

Comment: @Arun @Riccardo : I see this is more than a month old, but I have two comments I think might be important. First, the `.SD[CJ()]` part works as intended only because `nomatch=NA` by default. Might want to specify it explicitly just to be safe if the default is ever changed... Second, given the way it is used **within** `.SD`, `unique()` only includes the values of `id` and `membr` which are found **after** the data table has been subset according to `by=` rather than in the whole data table. This may be the intended behavior here (different sets of `membr` for each `event`) but maybe not.

Comment: @Arun Better safe than sorry, I've managed to shoot myself in the foot changing the default using `option()`, which you have graciously provided :) Re the second point, your answer does what the OP wants, my comment was directed at him, just in case he'd missed the difference.